# Raphaël: trying to add semi-animated text to Spinner graphic

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg, raphael

I'm trying to add a string of text to my Spinner graphic. For example, I want to be able to place the text either *below*, *next to*, or *inside* the Spinner wheel. The problem is, I don't know how to do that. Plus, I only want to semi-animate the text itself (if I animate it too much, the user may not be able to read it).

- Spinners created with Raphael:

  - http://jsfiddle.net/mnbishop017/vM9uk/
  - http://jsfiddle.net/mnbishop017/5BHhE/
- HTML ***example mockup*** of target results: http://jsfiddle.net/mnbishop017/4Enrk/

### Spinner code (JavaScript > Raphaël):

```
window.onload = function () {
    function spinner(holderid, R1, R2, count, stroke_width, color) {
        var sectorsCount = count || 12,
            color = color || "#fff",
            width = stroke_width || 15,
            r1 = Math.min(R1, R2) || 35,
            r2 = Math.max(R1, R2) || 60,
            cx = r2 + width,
            cy = r2 + width,
            r = Raphael(holderid, r2 * 2 + width * 2, r2 * 2 + width * 2),

            sectors = [],
            opacity = [],
            beta = 2 * Math.PI / sectorsCount,

            pathParams = {
                stroke: color,
                "stroke-width": width,
                "stroke-linecap": "round"
            };
        Raphael.getColor.reset();
        for (var i = 0; i < sectorsCount; i++) {
            var alpha = beta * i - Math.PI / 2,
                cos = Math.cos(alpha),
                sin = Math.sin(alpha);
            opacity[i] = 1 / sectorsCount * i;
            sectors[i] = r.path([
                ["M", cx + r1 * cos, cy + r1 * sin],
                ["L", cx + r2 * cos, cy + r2 * sin]
            ]).attr(pathParams);
            if (color == "rainbow") {
                sectors[i].attr("stroke", Raphael.getColor());
            }
        }
        var tick;
        (function ticker() {
            opacity.unshift(opacity.pop());
            for (var i = 0; i < sectorsCount; i++) {
                sectors[i].attr("opacity", opacity[i]);
            }
            r.safari();
            tick = setTimeout(ticker, 1000 / sectorsCount);
        })();
        return function () {
            clearTimeout(tick);
            r.remove();
        };
    }
    spinner("holder", 0, 120, 17, 2, "#000");
    // spinner("holder", -120, 120, 17, 2, "#005075"); Second spinner inserted above first spinner
};
```

### Mockup of desired result (in HTML)

```
<div>
    <!-- .placeholder is where the main Loading graphic (or animation) appears -->
    <div class="placeholder"></div>

    <!-- .text is where the Loading text appears: -->
    <!-- next to the graphic, vertically aligned to the middle -->
    <div class="text">loading</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing 2 libraries in the demos you give, the spinner is Raphael and the loading text is jQuery. I have made a combination of the two here - http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/vM9uk/13/ - which is a combination of this HTML:

```
<div class="box">
    <!-- .placeholder is where the main Loading graphic (or animation) appears -->
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
    <!-- .text is where the Loading text appears: next to the graphic -->
    <div class="text">loading <span class="dot">.</span>
 <span class="dot">.</span>
 <span class="dot">.</span>

    </div>
</div>
```

This JavaScript having included both RaphaelJS and jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var firstDot = $(".dot:first-of-type");
    var midDot = $(".dot:nth-of-type(2)");
    var lastDot = $(".dot:last-of-type");
    firstDot.hide();
    midDot.hide();
    lastDot.hide();
    $(".placeholder,.text").hide().fadeIn(1000, function () {
        var interv = 0;
        interv = setInterval(function () {
            firstDot.fadeIn(250, function () {
                midDot.fadeIn(250, function () {
                    lastDot.fadeIn(250);
                });
            }).delay(1000).fadeOut(250, function () {
                midDot.fadeOut(250, function () {
                    lastDot.fadeOut(250);
                });
            });
        }, 3000)
    });
});
```

and then some simple CSS to manipulate the location of the loading text and spinner.
However this is perhaps not ideal, as you're having to load both RaphaelJS and jQuery. It is all very possible to do this in pure RaphaelJS too; have a look at the reference here: http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html and the demos to get an idea of *what* you want to do.  As an example, here we've added a simple text element to the middle of the spinner and are fading it in and out in a continuous loop. (Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/vM9uk/14/)

```
tempText = r.text(R2, R2, "Loading ...");
        function fadeTextOut(){
            tempText.animate({opacity: 0}, 2500, fadeTextIn);
        }
        function fadeTextIn(){
            tempText.animate({opacity: 1}, 2500, fadeTextOut);
        }
        fadeTextOut();
```